# Nginx always returns html of main page instead of JSON data

Tags: json, django, nginx

I am newbie in nginx and web server technologies.
I have a django project and I am trying to use nginx + fastCGI on web server.

In my project I have urls which returns html and urls which returns JSON data.
When I tries to get JSON data nginx server always(no errors, no warnings) returns html from the main page.
Content type of response is "text/html", but should be "application/json".

There is my nginx configuration(This file is almost  default settings):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        server{
                listen 8080;

                location / {
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8881; 
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }

                location /static {
                        alias /home/user/xxx/templates;
                }
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}
```

I've tried to set up Apache with mod_python and I've got successful result.
What I am doing wrong? How should I properly configure nginx for getting JSON data?
Please ask me if you need more information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to add the application/json mime type to your mime.types configuration. [See these question and answers.](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,154321,154321#msg-154321)